# Sightseeing on Crack

Tags: knowledge, visual, story, steganography

Recently I went on an around-the-world vacation.

Unfortunately, I dropped my phone just as I was getting out of the cab at the airport before my first flight out. Not so bad in and of itself, but then a steamroller ran over it.

[image]

Not a problem, though. The screen on my phone doesn't affect the camera lens, so everything should be fine, am I right?

I was *wrong!*

[Strangely enough, the pictures all came out with the same pattern of cracks as could be seen on my screen.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deus_ex_machina)

Nevertheless I took some great pictures.

The minute I posted these on Facebook, I got a great job offer due to the sheer excellence of my photos!

---

<sub>Click thumbnails for high-resolution photos.</sub>

[image] [image]
`1.  _ _ _ _ _    _ _ _ _ _ _             2.  _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _`

[image] [image]
`3.  _ _ _ _ _ _   _ _ _                  4.  _ _ _ _ _ _ _   _ _ _ _ _`

[image] [image]
`5.  _ _ _ _ _ _                          6.  _ _ _ _ _ _   _ _   _ _ _ _ _ _ _`

[image] [image]
`7.  _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _   _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _  8.  _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _   _ _ _ _ _ _ _`

[image] [image]
`9.  _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _                    10. _ _ _ _ _ _   _ _ _ _ _`

[image] [image]
`11. _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _                12. _ _ _   _ _ _ _ _`

[image] [image]
`13. _ _ _ _ _ _   _ _ _ _ _   _ _ _ _ _  14. _ _ _ _ _   _ _ _ _`

[image] [image]
`15. _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _   _ _ _ _ _ _    16. _ _ _   _ _ _ _ _ _   _ _ _ _ _ _`

[image] [image]
`17. _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _   _ _ _ _ _    18. _ _ _   _ _ _ _ _ _`

---

> **Can you determine what the exact, word-for-word job title will be for me at my new job?**

Comment: crack photographer? :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

17 is

> the entrance to the Rockefeller Plaza

and for a final answer:

> Pick the $[(n-1)\pmod{10}+1]$-th letter from the $n$-th answer:
>
>  1. **G**rand Canyon
>  2. H**o**llywood
>  3. Ho**o**ver Dam
>  4. Nia**g**ara Falls
>  5. Zoca**l**o
>  6. Statu**e** of Liberty
>  7. Floren**c**e Cathedral
>  8. Victori**a** Harbour
>  9. Colliseu**m**
>  10. Eiffel Tow**e**r
>  11. **R**ijksmuseum
>  12. T**a**j Mahal
>  13. Sy**d**ney Opera House
>  14. Not**r**e Dame
>  15. Buck**i**ngham Palace
>  16. The Lo**v**ers Bridge
>  17. Rockef**e**ller Plaza
>  18. Red Squa**r**e
>
>  **GOOGLE CAMERA DRIVER**

Comment: I've added that to my answer with credit (and upvoted this of course) . Hope that's ok!

Comment: Unless 16 is my original guess of *"gur ybiref oevqtr"* (it was a comment on Chris's answer I replaced with *"gur ybhier oevqtr"* *facepalm*) in which case this fits perfectly

Comment: WP doesn't agree, and Google gives http://www.absolutetours.com/blog/lovers-bridge/, maybe 'In France, in May 2010 the city of Paris expressed concern over the growing number of love-locks on the Pont des Arts, Passerelle Léopold-Sédar-Senghor, and the Pont de l'Archevêché bridges',(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Love_lock) but this could be any bridge with love-locks.its probably better wait for the OP to make a statement!

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Yes, I found the same when looking it up, it just happened to be what I believed it to be called from when I first found out about it some years ago :) My memory is likely just failing me

Comment: The typo in #4 is fixed. :( The intended answer to #16 is indeed rot13(Gur Ybiref Oevqtr) as shown [here](https://www.listchallenges.com/top-250-famous-attractions-in-the-world/stats) and reinforced for me [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=lovers+bridge+paris&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjd-P6C-v_fAhWRiOAKHZ2fD5EQ_AUIDygC&biw=907&bih=446).

Comment: Good job finding the hidden message! I'll give you the check soon.

Comment: "taking the first, second, third, etc.. letters from each answer" --- probably easier to write it as "indexing into the location's name by its number"

Answer (score 5):

So here's a partial answer with some of the photos identified...

> 1. grand canyon
>  2. Hollywood
>  3. Hoover Dam
>  4.
>  5.
>  6. Statue of Liberty
>  7. Florence Cathedral (Credit: Nick A)
>  8. Victoria Harbour
>  9. Colliseum
>  10. Eiffel Tower
>  11. Rijksmuseum  (Credit: Mohirl)
>  12. Taj Mahal
>  13. Sydney Opera House
>  14. Notre Dame
>  15. Buckingham Palace
>  16. (Location IDed as Pont des Arts but not sure what words fit the blanks - Credit: jafe)
>  17. Rockefeller Plaza (Credit: JonMark Perry)
>  18. Red Square

I'm not sure where to go from here though or what the ones I've missed are...

Comment: A good start, +1! Check #3 (spelling) and #18 ( _  indicators).

Comment: #3 was a good old fashioned typo. #18 was me being careless with _ but obvious once I actually counted them. :)

Comment: 16 looks like rot13(Cbag qrf Negf), but the number of letters is off...

Comment: Also 5 could be rot13(Qhbzb) but again not enough letters...

Comment: You've definitely nailed the location for 16 (having google mapped it). I was wondering if it might be the building in the back it was named for but I can't seem to get that to fit either. I can't find where you think 5 is on google maps sadly so can't comment either way on that one. :(

Comment: @NickA: Spot on! Added to my answer (with due credit - I believe that is the correct protocol for this sort of thing).

Comment: @NickA: Ah yes. I meant to remove those (?) after Chowzen's comment on the assumption that they would have said if those were wrong. Thanks for the reference (I did likewise finding a matching view for 7 to confirm your suggestions).

Comment: Taking the rot13(agu yrggre bs rnpu jbeq (jvgu ybbcvat)) plus Nathan's answer yields rot13(tbbt?rpnzrzzbrp?ne) which is close to rot13(tbbtyr pnz ? pne)

Comment: Also 16 could be leaving rot13(gur ybhier zhfrhz) which fits the blanks.

Answer (score 3):

Number 4 is

> Niagara Falls

You can tell from the building next to it and the train on the hill.

Comment: Yeah, for sure - It doesn't quite fit, but off-by-one could be an _ typo. The sign thus says rot13(snyyf vapyvar cynmn) and you can get the image from the street view from the rot13(avntnen cnexjnl).

Comment: Plus if you then take the rot13(agu yrggre bs rnpu ragel) you get rot13(tbbt?r pnz) which is starting to look promising!

Comment: I thought that this might be the hardest one to get, big +1! I didn't even notice the sign. :O

Answer (score 3):

Number 7 is:

> Florence Cathedral

Number 5 appears to be a picture of:

> [Mexico City Metropolitan Cathedral](https://www.google.com/maps/@19.432744,-99.1323154,3a,75y,1.73h,89.77t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sfbi9KwQuD-gYAIynIqrlGQ!2e0!7i13312!8i6656)
>
>
>  The square it is on is called Plaza de la Constitución. More commonly known as the *Zócalo*

Number 16 is:

> Pont des Arts but I hear it more often called "the padlock bridge"
>
>
>  I would guess this is <s>The Louvre Bridge The Louvre Museum (Credit: LambdaBeta)</s>
>
>
>  Given what the answer appears to be, my original guess of The Lovers Bridge appears to fit here, unfortunately I deleted that comment on Chris' answer...

Comment: I already gave you a +1 for this answer, but want to reinforce it. Nice job on getting rot13(Gur Ybiref Oevqtr)!

Answer (score 2):

Partial remaining ones:

Is #11 the

> Rijksmuseum in Amsterdam?

And #4 has

> A sign just below the rightmost track that I can't quite make out. Something plaza? Which fits the second word

Comment: #11 definitely correct. I've added it to my answer (with credit) and upvoted yours. Hope that's ok!

Comment: Sure! You've done most of the work, only added it separately rather than a comment on yours as I wasn't sure and figured it might spark someone's imagination if mine was wrong

Answer (score 1):

Was your job

> A quiz show artist

Because

> They wanted you for a show within which guests have to recognise famous landmarks behind the crack, hence the space for letters beneath the photographs.

Answer (score 1):

Will you be:

> A Google Maps Street View Driver

Because:

> All the images appear to be taken from Google Maps Street View

Comment: Nice guess, but this isn't a very "steganographical" answer. :) Remember, I need an "exact, word-for-word job title."